# Hive UDF to write bytes directly

Tags: hadoop, hive, udf

I am creating some UDAF functions where I want to end up writing a byte array directly out to disk.

I had envisioned something like this for my terminate...

```
public BytesWritable terminate() throws HiveException {
        byte[] bitvalues = new byte[]{
                (byte) 0x01,
                (byte) 0x02,
                (byte) 0x04,
                (byte) 0x08
        };

        BytesWritable bw = new BytesWritable();

        bw.set(bitvalues, 0, bitvalues.length);
        return bw;
}
```

I then thought I could do something like this in Hive:

```
add jar myCustom.jar;
create temporary function foo as 'com.example.foo';

INSERT OVERWRITE local DIRECTORY 'foo-results'
SELECT foo(some_field) FROM some_table;
```

The end goal is to have a file 4 bytes long with the exact byte literals fed through my `terminate` method.

I think the problem is that my byte array is wrapped in the BytesWritable, and *something* is deciding to encode the byte array in base64.